# Reverse proxy to put header value as parameter to url

Tags: apache-http-server, proxy, http, iis

I need to set up reverse proxy which will put header value from original request as a parameter to the destination url. The reason for this is purelly application specific and unfortunatelly I cannot change this application.
 For example I need the folowing https://a.com with http header myparam=abcd  i need to be proxied to http://b.com/?val=abcd

Is it possible to configure IIS or Apache to perform such task ? If so, can you explain how ?

Comment: I see you unaccepted my answer and did not accept the other answer. Are you still looking for answers / more details? If not, you should accept one of the answers.

Comment: @user49740 No, just forgot to mark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in Apache 2.4:

```
# (In a VirtualHost for a.com)
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://b.com$1?val=%{HTTP:myparam} [QSA,P]
```

Example rewrites (if the header `myparam` has value `myvalue`):

- `a.com` becomes `http://b.com?val=myvalue`
- `a.com/path/here` becomes `http://b.com/path/here?val=myvalue`
- `a.com/path?a=b&c=d` becomes `http://b.com/path?a=b&c=d&val=myvalue`

If the `myparam` header does not exist, `a.com/x` will redirect to `http://b.com/x?val=`. If you want to redirect to `http://b.com/x`, you can use the following longer version of the above:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:myparam} .
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1?val=%{HTTP:myparam} [QSA,L,P]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com$1 [P]
```

Related links:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html

Answer (score 1):

For IIS you could use the [URL Rewrite extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) :

> IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 enables Web administrators to create powerful
>   rules to implement URLs that are easier for users to remember and
>   easier for search engines to find. By using rule templates, rewrite
>   maps, .NET providers, and other functionality integrated into IIS
>   Manager, Web administrators can easily set up rules to define URL
>   rewriting behavior based on HTTP headers, HTTP response or request
>   headers, IIS server variables, and even complex programmatic rules. In
>   addition, Web administrators can perform redirects, send custom
>   responses, or stop HTTP requests based on the logic expressed in the
>   rewrite rules.
>
> Works With: IIS 7, IIS 7.5, IIS 8

A walkthrough can be found on :
[Creating Rewrite Rules for the URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).